# How many dynos do I need for 1 app and 1 worker on Heroku?

Tags: heroku, devops

Hi I'm a little bit confused with Heroku pricing.

I want to host my app on heroku, my app consist of a node js app (rest API backend), a node js worker, redis and Mongo DB database.

In hobby plan it said have an "10 Process Types", i don't really sure what is process type mean even though i already read the docs.

Do i need separate dyno for my app and my worker? or 1 dynos can contain 1 app and 10 different worker?

---

From my current understanding, what i need is :

- 1 Hobby dyno plan for my app and my worker : $7
- shared cluster 1 GB mlab mongodb database : $18
- Hobby dev redis plan : $0
  Total : $25

Am i correct?

Sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Heroku terminology, you need to create an Heroku App having:

- one Hobby web dyno - for your REST api 7$/month
- one Hobby worker dyno - for your worker 7$/month
- one mLab MongoDB Shared cluster 1GB add-on 18$/month
- one Heroku Redis Hobby Dev add-on 0$/month

For a total of 32$/month prorated to the seconds

To respond to your doubts about process types, consider that the above mentioned dynos have two different types: one is **web** the other is **worker**

The **web** type is a special reserved word that indicates to Heroku which is the dyno that will receive the external http traffic. The **worker** type instead is simply a logical label that, being different from **web**, simply indicates to Heroku that it won’t receive any external traffic and you are free to name it as you prefer (e.g. myworker, scheduler, taskhandler ...)